# Relationship of Columns - find the highest value

Tags: python, plot, relationship

I'm currently struggling with a problem I am not really sure of how to describe it.
I have two columns, one shows the hours with two digits (e.g 10 for 10 am to 10.59am and 17 for 17pm to 17.59pm).
A second column shows KIOSK ID's referencing to the hour. Each appearance of a Kiosk ID stands for a customer visit.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agaxA.png)

I need to plot the peak hours of each of the kiosks.

I tried to connect both columns by using pd.crosstabs but unfortunately I have no idea how to retrieve the maximum value for each hour and how to assign the highest value of each hour to the corresponding kiosk. All I got so far is the following:

[combining both columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFjUB.png)

Thanks for hint of adding pictures. 
Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: please show the code you have tried, as well an your input data and expected output, I'm sure we could get an answer then!

Comment: please share the an example of the datas and the desired output with if possible any attempt. Else this question is likely to get close or downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to groupby the hour and kiosk,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'hour': [10,10,10,10,12,12,12],
                   'kiosk': ['A','A','A','B','A','A','C']})
df.groupby(['hour','kiosk']).size().unstack()

kiosk    A    B    C
hour                
10     3.0  1.0  NaN
12     2.0  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried groupby as well. Once I have the "matrix" how can I retrieve the highest value for each kiosk without losing the ID information?

Comment: You can use df.max(axis=1), can you upvote and mark as resolved please